# Pivoting the columns keeping certain columns as static in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

i have a table with values like this.Any suggestions on how to PIVOT this keeping the date, page and ID columns without any change,But pivoting the action column based on dynamic values ?

I'm using postgres version11, Any idea how we can do it ?

**Sample input**

```
date            page         action         id.     value
"2020-10-14"    "/page 1/"  "impressions"   6693    2
"2020-10-23"    "/page 2/"  "clicks"        3024    1
"2020-11-14"    "/page 3/"  "impressions"   3425    8
"2020-10-02"    "/page 1/"  "impressions"   6694    5
"2020-11-09"    "/page 4/"  "impressions"   3453    1
"2020-11-14"    "/page 1/"  "impressions"   3429    7
"2020-10-21"    "/page 5/"  "clicks"        6690    6
"2020-11-08"    "/page 6/"  "impressions"   27462   1
```

Expected output

```
date            page         impressions. clicks         id.  
"2020-10-14"    "/page 1/"      2             0          6693   
"2020-10-23"    "/page 2/"      0             1          3024   
"2020-11-14"    "/page 3/"      8             0          3425   
"2020-10-02"    "/page 1/"      5             0          6694   
"2020-11-09"    "/page 4/"      1             0          3453   
"2020-11-14"    "/page 1/"      7             0          3429   
"2020-10-21"    "/page 5/"      0             6          6690   
"2020-11-08"    "/page 6/"      1             0          27462
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional expressions:

```
SELECT
    date,
    page,
    (CASE action WHEN 'impressions' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS impressions,
    (CASE action WHEN 'clicks' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS clicks,
    id
FROM
    that_table
```

This won't work with dynamic values of course, as you cannot (should not) generate columns dynamically.